# Add tags to enclose existing table

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have an existing table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in JavaScript, I have already obtained this table:

```
var isert = main_code.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

How to use JavaScript to attach tags to this table so it looks like:

```
<div id=extra>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>content
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

PS: It seems that `insertAdjacentHTML` only works on current `<table>`tag, not entire `<table></table>`.

Thank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tables = main_code.getElementsByTagName("table");
for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var _t = tables[i];
    var parent = _t.parentNode;
    div.id = "extra";
    parent.replaceChild(div, _t);
    div.appendChild(_t);
}
```

Although, this adds the same `id` to multiple `div` container, if there are more than one `table`. You might want to use `div.className = 'extra'` instead.

Comment: Hi Mr Amberlamps, I tried your code for dealing with multiple tables together and had some trouble. see fiddle [>>FIDDLE LINK<<](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/wGp8j/1/) It seems work unwell...

Comment: @Darklizard: Yes, you were right. Did not expect that kind of behaviour. I fixed the code in my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Fantastic! It works perfect in my project! Is it means replaceChild() method just replace its origion content with div-enclosed one, so that its place can be kept!? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Darklizard: You completely got it right! Great that it works!